# How do I configure nginx rewrite rules to strip off the index page for a single page JS application and redirect non-hashed URLs to hashed URLs?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm a software developer writing a single page JS application. I am by no means a sysadmin, so please bear with me.

What I would like to accomplish is for redirects to occur anytime a user hits my site with one of two potentially common/unwanted URL patterns.

1. mysite.com/index.html -> redirect to mysite.com
2. mysite.com/path/they/remember -> redirect to hashed version: mysite.com/#/path/they/remember

I have tried various ways, but I keep running into redirect loops. Here is the configuration I have currently:

Note: You'll notice that /api also needs all requests to be internally redirected through a lightweight oauth proxy, so whatever solution I use cannot interrupt this redirection.

```
server {

# Redirect all requests through /api/ to apiproxy.php
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /apiproxy.php/$1 last;
}

location / {
    index index.html
}

# use case #1 (combined with use case #2 optionally, a url such as mysite.com/index.html/path/they/remember)
location ~ /index.html/?(.*) {
    return 301 http://mysite.com\#/$1;
}

location ~ /(.*) {
    return 301 http://mysite.com\#/$1;
}
```

This setup gives me redirect loops all around. Does anyone have any suggestions or know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do the nginx way?

Answer (score 0):

first, increase the loglevel and check your logs.

you last location-block seems to be bogus.

also, `return 301 http://mysite.com\#/$1;` doesnt seem to be legit; did you wanted to do
`return 301  http://mysite.com/\#/$1/;` ?

do you need to escape `#`?